# jQuery Slider animations not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am following directions from a video series for this slider and my syntax is exactly the same as his other than image names and id values. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_P3Auq-U8c

All files are local because this is just practice. I've got a link to everything in my drop box. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/z4deqyemmf8xnn4/AACz7gv2dkBQHpM5F__EA-Era

I've got a file for jQuery, a file for the slider animation, and I'm using script tags from the Google jQuery library.

This is my index file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>jQuery Slider</title>

    <style type="text/css">

.slider {
    width: 640px;
    height: 360px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background-image: url(img/loadersmall.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
.shadow {
    background-image: url(img/shadow.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top;
    width: 700px;
    height: 144px;
    margin: -60px auto;
}
.slider img {
    width: 640px;
    height: 360px;
    display: none;
}

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function Slider() {
            $(".slider #26").show("fade", 500);
            $(".slider #26").delay(5500).hide("slide", {direction: 'left'}, 500);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="Slider();">
    <div class="slider">
        <img id="26" src="img/26.png" border="0" alt="Funnymouth">
        <img id="52" src="img/52.png" border="0" alt="Come">
        <img id="29" src="img/29.png" border="0" alt="Xorax">
    </div>

    <div class="shadow"></div>

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slider.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't know what else to do with it to make it work. Maybe I didn't copy the jQuery right? Maybe there's a typo somewhere? Hope someone can help me figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

First you are including jquery file 3 times and the slider.js file doesn't contain any functions

Here is a better way to implement a slider using jquery

```
slider
  |--index.html
  |--slider.js
  |--slider.css
  |--img/
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>Slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="slider.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="slider">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="img/img1.gif" alt="image"></li>
        <li><img src="img/img2.gif" alt="image"></li>
        <li><img src="img/img3.gif" alt="image"></li>
        <li><img src="img/img4.gif" alt="image"></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="slider-nav">
    <button data-dir="prev">Previous</button>
    <button data-dir="next">Next</button>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="slider.js"></script>
<script>

(function() {
    var container = $('div.slider').css('overflow', 'hidden').children('ul'),
        slider = new Slider( container, $('#slider-nav') );

    slider.nav.find('button').on('click', function() {
        slider.setCurrent( $(this).data('dir') );
        slider.transition();
    });     
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**slider.js**

```
function Slider( container, nav ) {
    this.container = container;
    this.nav = nav.show();

    this.imgs = this.container.find('img');
    this.imgWidth = this.imgs[0].width; // 600
    this.imgsLen = this.imgs.length;

    this.current = 0;
}

Slider.prototype.transition = function( coords ) {
    this.container.animate({
        'margin-left': coords || -( this.current * this.imgWidth )
    });
};

Slider.prototype.setCurrent = function( dir ) {
    var pos = this.current;

    pos += ( ~~( dir === 'next' ) || -1 );
    this.current = ( pos < 0 ) ? this.imgsLen - 1 : pos % this.imgsLen;

    return pos;
};
```

**slider.css**

```
body {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
}
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#slider-nav { 
    display: none; 
    margin-top: 1em;
}
#slider-nav button {
    padding: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.slider {
    width: inherit;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.slider ul {
    width: 10000px;
    list-style: none;
}
.slider li {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: The googleapis.com links were both different. One is supposed to be to smooth out the animation. I didn't think about the slider file not having a function though. Not sure how I missed that. I'll try to mess with that for a bit and if I can't get it to work, I'll take a look at your code. Thanks!